# Rethrow Exception and Catch Again

Tags: c#, exception

I am using C# and wondered if it was possible to rethrow an exception from a `try/catch` and have a later `catch` statement recatch it?

```
try {
// 1. Try some operation
    //Failed operations

// 2. Throw an exception
    throw new IOException("I tried my best");
} catch(IOException) {
// 3. Try some specific recovery operation
    //Failed operations

//4. Rethrow and try again
    throw;
}

... Some more specific exception handlers

} catch(Exception) {
// 5. Re-caught here as a last-ditch effort, generic recovery operation
    //Process here
} finally {
    //...
}
```

Comment: You can nest try/catch block.

Comment: Answer: Yes! But only in another scope :)

Comment: Not in the same try-catch, but at a higher level

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only if your catch statement throws to another try/catch, for example:

```
try{

    ...

   try{
        ...
   }
   catch(ExceptionA a)
   {
      throw;
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
       //will not not catch ExceptionA (rethrow or not)
   }
}
catch(ExceptionA a)
{
    //this would catch the re-throw
}
catch( Exception e)
{
}
```

Instead why don't you catch the general `Exception` and then case the exception types?

```
try{
        ...
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
       if (e is ExceptionA){
            ...
       }
   }
```

Or put logic on the `finally`

```
 System.Exception thrownException = null;
 try{
        ...
   }
   catch( ExceptionA a)
   {
      thrownException = a;
      ...  // do special handling...
   }
   catch( ExceptionB b)
   {
      thrownException = b;
      ...  // do special handling...
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
      ...
   }
   finally{
     if ( thrownException != null ) {
          ...   //case the type here or use some other way to identify..
     }
   }
```

Comment: Ok... that's what I was afraid of. :( Thank you.

Comment: If I felt mean, I could use `goto`s... But I not feeling it. :)

Comment: why not just catch exception and case the exception type?

Comment: That's a possible workaround, if I finish and jump between `case` stateements. I would do that, but switch on type always gave me funny feelings, as I came from a `C++` background, and that's a especially a no-no there.

Comment: i've not ever had an issue with doing logic based on types, isn't that a no-no because of the multiple inheritance of classes.  C# wouldn't have that issue as long as your logic is done in the correct order.

Comment: How would you recommend simulating a rethrow-and-recatch with your switch on type logic?

Comment: if you're in the general exception block why must you rethrow?  In your example if the exception is an IOException you perform some re-try logic and if it fails you rethrow so it gets logged or cleaned up?

Comment: You wouldn't need to rethrow would you?  why wouldn't you just handle it there?  OR add a boolean in the finally, if an exception occurred do something....

Comment: Good idea on the `finally`. In my code, this is supposed to handle a series of exception types, with a generic catch statement that will work for unhandled exception types, or if any of the existing type-specific catch blocks fail.

Comment: understood, then I guess you could put all your extra logic in the finally and keep all your catch statements as-is.  You'll need to do some sort of logic in the finally..  got to pay for it somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

Your code should work, however the real problem is that exceptions should be used to inform outer code parts about the fact, that something went wrong. Throwing MANUALLY an exception in the try section and catching it in the following catch section is pointless. If you know you can't process some IO operation, handle it right away with an if-else statement. Using try-catch for that is without a doubt a bad, inefficient practice.

Comment: This was a simple example, not a snapshot of my actual code. I also disagree that this is bad practice, since `try/catch` statements are doing exactly what they are supposed to do, separating the main code from error handling conditions. These two operations should not be mixed. Also, if you are concerned about efficiency, that would be negligible in this case, since there would be next to no stack unwinding when the exception is thrown.

Comment: @spryno724 No, try/catch is not supposed to handle an error that you've just created inside the try section. It's supposed to handle internal errors. What possible advantages does the try/catch give you over the simple if-else statement?

Comment: I see what you are saying now... Yes, I agree that would be a bad idea in practice. This was just a simple example to communicate an idea.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure (because of variables scope, because c# is not the language I'm now using, and because of possible side effects due to the new added variable, and because *it does not look to be a good coding practice*), but would that work:

```
try{
     ...
}
catch(ExceptionA a)
{
   exception = a;  // "Store" the exception in a variable
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    //will not not catch ExceptionA (rethrow or not)
}

try
{
    if (exception)
        throw exception;  // kind of rethrow if variable is set
}
catch(ExceptionA a)
{
    //this would catch the re-throw
}
catch( Exception e)
{
}
```